# how can i start directx game development using c++

Tags: c++, directx

i know about fundamental programming concepts, OOP concepts, Data structure concepts of c++ but how can i start game development please suggest me tutorials or book which is easy to understand because from one week i'm searching about c++ directx development

Comment: Asking for a book is off-topic in SO.

Comment: from where i ask this question bro :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Books by Frank D Luna at [d3dcoder.net](http://www.d3dcoder.net/) are your best friends, regarding 3D graphics. Note, that other parts of DirectX are rarely used in game development.

In case if you want some framework, not only 3D API (which is Direct3D) - you'd better check [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/) or [SDL](https://www.libsdl.org/)

Comment: Thanks Brother do u have tutorial about this and after this book am i able to develop may own game ?